When reserve(new_size) is called for unordered_set/unordered_map - does it cause allocation of new array of buckets?
AFAIU (maybe I am wrong), unordered_set/unordered_map use underlying array or vector for buckets, and in each bucket there is a list of keys (or key-value).
So when we want more buckets, larger array needs to be allocated and buckets moved into it?
I.e. does it work similar to vector::reserve?
(except that for vector elements are moved using move constructor, and here pointers are moved as it is list inside bucket).

Probably. The standard doesn't say explicilty how the buckets are organized, only what operations you can perform on them. There are lots of detailed requiements for these operations, so a very limited set of options. But still.

What we can tell is that if the new number of elements after the last insertion is greater than max_load_factor() * bucket_count(), then a rehashing will occur and all iterators will be invalidated. So we can easily deduce that a reallocation happened. We can say it's conceptually similar to std::vector::reserve() except that there is a hash/rehash that doesn't exist in std::vector (and I don't know if the rules for the new allocated size are the same).

@Fareanor, not really like in vector, as once vector re-allocated, all its elements are moved using move constructor; here each key/element sits in bucket which is a list. So you do not need to call move constructor, just move the list which moves pointers. I.e. in vector all your elements are in contiguous storage, whilst in every bucket all elements are not in contiguous storage.

@AndreyRubliov A std::vector of buckets would do the same :) It's up to the bucket implementation to define how they will be moved not to the container storing them.

Increasing the capacity of the underlying storage may trigger a rehashing, which is not as cheap as you think.

For any unordered associative container (such as std::unordered_set) a, a.reserve(n) is equivalent to:
a.rehash(ceil(n / a.max_load_factor()))

... which ensures that once rehashing is done, a.bucket_count() >= ceil(n / a.max_load_factor()) is true.
In other words, the bucket count is (possibly) increased so that no rehashing is necessary until more than n unique elements are in the container.
By comparison, std::vector::reserve(n) ensures that until the size of the vector exceeds n, the vector isn't resized.

Thanks for this! So does reserve(...) allocate new memory in case rehash did not happen, i.e. size is not enough to trigger reharsh?

@AndreyRubliov if the size is already sufficient, reserve() shouldn't result in any rehashing/allocation.
